# How to get a entry from each month

Tags: channel-entries, channel, calendar

I would like to get the last entry of a channel from each month.
is there any way to do it with channel entry module?

like:
2015, 01 : last entry is "hello 1";
2015, 02 : last entry is "hello 2";
2015, 03 : last entry is "hell 3";

it gives me a hard time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the channel entries tag with the [archive month links](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/archive_month_links.html) tag.

```
{exp:channel:month_links channel="YOUR_CHANNEL" limit="12"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="YOUR_CHANNEL" limit="1" year="{year}" month="{month_num}"}
        {entry_date format="%Y  , %m"} : last entry is "{title}";
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:month_links}
```

Comment: I think this will work I need to test it is out.. thanks very much you lighted my vision

Comment: thanks very Much this solved my issue . you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `month` and `year` parameters?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="YOURCHANNELNAME" year="2015" month="01" status="not closed" limit="1" sort="asc" orderby="date" disable="categories|pagination|category_fields|member_data"}
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you're on an archive page like:

```
http:///www.your-domain-name.com/blog/archive/2015/01
```

You could do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" year="{segment_3}" month="{segment_4}" status="not closed" limit="1" sort="asc" orderby="date" disable="categories|pagination|category_fields|member_data"}
        ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can read more here:

[year=, month=, day=](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#year-month-day)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much that's helps but I think this will return only a single entry. I need to return Multi entries ,, last one of each month.. thanks to you to share Year,Month , Day parameters

Comment: Then change the limit parameter.

Comment: He's trying to output one entry from each month on one page, without embeds or php he can't use segments. Increasing the limit will only output more entries from each month.